# Switching between projects in different Repository Management Services (bitbucket, GitLab) using git

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, ssh-keys, git-repo

I have already a project on `GitLab` which I've been working on, and recently I've been assigned another project on `bitbucket`.

I already understand that when I work on a project and I need to `push`, `pull`, `add`, `commit` etc. then I need to ensure I'm already in that project's directory, but what other factors do I need to be aware of? I'd like to avoid any conflicts or embarrassing situations like committing code to the wrong project, so perhaps I need to switch between different repos.

A while back a former colleague configured in my `.bash_profile` file. The below commands were for a project I no longer work on, so I don'T use this anymore but it's still there in my `.bash_profile` file:

```
set_companyX_git(){
  git config --global http.sslcertpasswordprotected true
  git config --global http.sslCert /Users/my_mbp/Software/ssl_project/keystore.p12
}

unset_companyX_git(){
  git config --unset --global http.sslcertpasswordprotected
  git config --unset --global http.sslCert
}
```

I'd like to add something similar in my `.bash_profile` again, but I'm not sure how correct these commands are. Hopefully a git pro can put me on the right path here.

Due to my existing project on Gitlab I'll already have a ssh key, but must this key be individual to every repo, or to every Repository Management Services, or does it not matter so long as I have a key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bunch of questions here, but I'll answer them as best I can in the order they were asked.

1. `what other factors do I need to be aware of?` - Your commits will all have the author details (name and email address) specified in your global config. If that's acceptable, then great; if that might cause a problem, then you may need to run `git config user.name "Your Name for This Repo"` and `git config user.email "foo@bar.baz"` in each repo that needs to differ from the global config.
2. `I'd like to add something similar in my .bash_profile again, but I'm not sure how correct these commands are.` Those should only be necessary if you have to provide a password for a TLS key. If you aren't hosting repos locally, then you probably don't need them.
3. `must this key be individual to every repo, or to every Repository Management Services, or does it not matter so long as I have a key?` It doesn't matter as long as you have a key, though each remote host will limit that key to one user account. (In other words, if you have UserA on GitLab and UserB on Bitbucket, then you can use the same key for both - but if you have both UserA and UserB on GitLab, then they'll need separate keys.)

Comment: Remond: thank you, this was exactly the clarification I was looking for. Strangely, after using the command ls `-al ~/.ssh` I only saw the `config`, and no `id_rsa` file. I was expecting to see this file in this directory, because I'm already push/pulling to a git repo. In any case, I see now the correct way to use git is simply ensure you're in the right directory (and often env), and that's it. Thanks again.